# TurnkeyLinux Django installation. Default admin password?

Tags: python, django, turnkeylinux.org

I have searched elsewhere and can-not find this information anywhere.

I have installed Django via a 'turnkeyLinux' installation for my VPS. This is after multiple failed attempts of setting this up manually. To my delightment, it appears to work. However, when trying to access the Django admin interface I am prompted for a username/password.

Thinking it may be my VPS ROOT details, I try those. No go.

I then find TurnKeyLinux's Django page here: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/django where it says the admin username is 'admin' and that the password is 'set at first boot'.

I have no idea what the admin password is, was hoping there was a default one. Is there a way I can find or rest this password via SSH?

Please save me from pulling out all my hair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you'd either use the `manage.py changepassword` command or change it through the console. More info can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#changing-passwords).

If you can SSH in, execute either of those solutions in the project root and you should be set. The Turnkey docs suggest the `/var/www/project` is the example project root.

Comment: Thanks, I have tired this but I still can not seem to get it.

/var/www/project# python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> manage.py changepassword


I have also tried different variations, including adding the user 'admin' to the command, etc. I see that manage.py resides in the /var/www/project dir but I even if a vi edit the file, there doesn't appear to be any passwords stored within.

Sorry for the horribly formatted responses. I guess line breaks and what-not are not welcome.

Comment: If you want to execute a command in a directory, you need to include the path. So try `./manage.py changepasswod admin` in the project root, or `/var/www/project/manage.py changepassword admin` elsewhere in the filesystem.

Comment: Ah, I've got it figured out now. The default password was simply, "turnkey". I've since been able to change it via the admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

uname: `admin`

pass: The password is setup at first boot. If you did not set one manually, you probably "entered" through it by mistake... try `admin:""`